# How to check whether the geofence is already created or not in the device? If it is not need to add the geofence in my android app?

Tags: android-geofence

I have tried to check whether the geofence event is already created or not.How to check geofence already created in the device or not?

Comment: I want to check whether the device already have geofence data or not. If it don't have geofence event. I want to add geofence at that time.

Comment: Please add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: i tried several logic's. I am not able to do that. none of them are correct that is why i am approaching. I DON'T KNOW the logic.

Comment: It is not shameful to show some non-working code. It is encouraged because in this case others can point you what mistakes you've done and not implement that for you from scratch.